# Tidyverse googledrive - download from Google Drive to RStudio

Tags: r, google-drive-api, tidyverse

I am trying to download files from my Google Drive into an R environment running from RStudio Server on an EC2 instance.

I have installed googledrive so I could connect Google Drive to the R environment.  I have duly supplied my password.  I have checked that the connection works correctly by using drive_find(pattern="Lxxx"), and verified this produced the correct list of files. But

drive_download("L2018")

returns an error:

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function ":="

How can I make this download work?  I thought maybe my list of packages had somehow renamed that function so I removed all of it and restarted R, loading only googledrive.  But I got the same message.  Thank you for any advice on this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `googledrive` may be missing a dependency.  Try adding `library(rlang)`.  `rlang` defines `:=`.

Comment: Well, that moved the dial, so I upvoted... but it still doesn't work, now it says:   Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list.
Problem variables: '`:=`(!(!nm), val)'

Comment: Not sure where that's coming from, but errors with that wording seem to pop up when people are using tidyverse packages.  I'd try updating to all of the latest versions of tidyverse packages, but I don't know if that will help.  You might also try submitting an issue to https://github.com/tidyverse/googledrive.

Comment: great idea.  I submitted the experience to github.  In the meantime I found out that if I use a dribble instead of a filename as argument to drive_download, then the download works although there is an error message afterward.  After all, googledrive is still in version 0.1.1 ...